# Architecture Question - How to use Dynamic User Controls in WPF and C#

Tags: c#, wpf, inheritance, user-controls

I'm using **C#** and **WPF** for this project.

The main goal of the Application is to create a string which will run as Client in Windows Command Line:

> **Exe File1** **parameter1** **parameter1_value** **paramter2** **paramter2_value**

Example:

> update_respgrp.exe -c Assembly -a IskModAuthor -t last -f obj.txt

The EXE File should be change following the user request.
The parameters after that are depend on the EXE File the user choose.

In order to fulfill it I created a dynamic User Control (we will Call it **Main User Control**) which contain 4 other sub user controls: 
[Main User Control Screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MIaS9.png)

The Main User Control have 3 Sub User Controls that usually doesn't need to be change (UC2-UC4).

The Problem is with UC1 which contain all the parameters and their values.

Once I click a button the user control should be change according to the button i pressed on.

Each User Control that Replace UC1 Have different amount of Text Box and Combo Box.

I wanted to use inheritance, but I understood that WPF doesn't really support inheritance (correct me if i'm wrong).

So I tried to load the user control dynamically. I think I understand how to load the User Control Dynamically (correct me if i'm wrong):

```
   private void GenerateClientBlock()
    {
        Type newType = Type.GetType("ClientCatalogWPF.GeneralClientControl", true, true);
        object o = Activator.CreateInstance(newType, "UC1");
        ClientControl.Children.Add((UIElement)o);
    }
```

The problem begin when I want to get all UC1 Controls Values into variable.
The main UC doesn't now the UC1 Controls, cause they change dynamically.
Hopefully I succeed to describe the whole picture.

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: When you say inheritance, do you mean like in winforms when you created a base control and inherited from that keeping the look of it? That means you are using `WPF` wrong. DataTemplates are used to keep the look of the app consistent. Invest time in doing this app properly using MvvM, otherwise you will have problem after problem.

Comment: I'm not familiar with Mvvm. The Concept was WindowsFroms, but i choose to use WPF instead because it's modern. I Prefer steel using C#. Do you any other suggestion to fulfill this Application? I Don't have to use Inheritance

Comment: You're talking about code re-usability which is fine, but WPF doesn't use GDI or GDI+, it's uisng DirectX instead. All of the methods used in `WinForms` are therefore not applicable. Check the Handle on WPF window, it's always the default one. Like I said, use MvvM then you will have a central point to control the user controls and use commands! It will make all of this go away.